# Swift : App crashes while loading large size html using UIWebView due to high memory usage

Tags: ios, swift

Tried with WKWebView but that didn't work. View hierarchy - Viewcontroller -> Tableview -> Tableviewcell -> UIWebview inside cell. Based on content height of html, cell height is adjusted.

Comment: are these HTML files getting from the server? or loading from the bundle?

Comment: from the bundle

Comment: func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        self.height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        self.heightConstraint = webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.height)
        self.heightConstraint.isActive = true
        
        self.tblList.reloadData()
    }